# Android - Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: android, json, http

Im trying to connect mysql with android but it throw me an error.
**Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException:**

Below is my code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.pherma.net84.net/admin/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

But the URL s working fine. Please copy n paste the url.

Comment: Does the internet connection of your device work correctly? And do you have specified the 'internet' permission in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: remove this line httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

Comment: its works now...my bad....didnt give network permission in manifes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forget to put network permission in manifest. Working fine now.